# List on python appending always the same value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following code inside a while loop.

```
if gender == 0 and len(men) < 51 :
    height = float((random.uniform(1.3, 1.9) + (random.randint(10, 20)/100.)).__format__('.2f'))
    weight = float((random.uniform(45, 100) * height).__format__('.2f'))
    attr['height'] = height 
    attr['weight'] = weight

    men.append(attr)
```

So this code always gives some random height and random weight. But outsite de loop (when it is finished). If I do `print men`, I get the following result:

```
[{'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}, {'weight': 76.64, 'height': 1.75}]
```

Its always the same thing. But, if I instead of using `attr[height] = height; attr['weight] = weight` and use `men.append(height); men.append(weight)` I get the following result:

`print men
[1.91, 145.95, 1.64, 95.66, 2.0, 159.94, 1.74, 143.36, 1.68, 97.99, 1.6, 90.11, 1.63, 116.2, 1.56, 96.8, 2.04, 198.56, 1.56, 145.96, 1.44, 67.57, 1.83, 94.97, 1.85, 175.69, 1.84, 101.84, 1.54, 135.0, 1.41, 101.23, 1.92, 167.59, 1.74, 142.55, 1.49, 129.07, 1.83, 161.28, 1.59, 97.16, 1.46, 134.53, 2.03, 158.72, 2.05, 184.43, 1.97, 162.81]`

If I print attr inside the loop it always has a different value ( its what I want). But when I append it to my list, the values of my list are always the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your post and include loop to get clear picture.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: It looks like you are updating the same dict, you probably just need a new dict or a copy, e.g. `attr = {'height': height, 'weight': weight}` or `men.append(attr.copy())`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simplified example of your code currently to explain more fully *why* your results are the way they are:

```
all_items = []
new_item = {}
for i in range(0,5):
    new_item['a'] = i
    new_item['b'] = i

    all_items.append(new_item)
    print new_item
    print hex(id(new_item))  # print memory address of new_item

print all_items
```

Notice the memory address for your object is the same *each time* you go through your loop. This means that your object being added is the same, each time. So when you print the final list, you are printing the coordinates of the same object at every location in the loop.

Each time you go through the loop, the values are being updated - imagine you are painting over the same wall every day. The first day, it might be blue. The next day, you repaint the same wall (or object) and then it's green. The last day you paint it orange and it's orange - the same wall is *always* orange now. Your references to the `attr` object are like saying you have the same wall.

Even though you looked at the wall after painting it, the color changed. But afterwards it is a orange wall - even if you look at it 5 times.

When we make the object as a new object in each iteration, notice two things happen:

1. the memory address changes
2. the values persist as unique values

This is similar to painting *different* walls. After you finish painting the last one, each of the previous walls is still painted the color you first painted it.

You can see this in the following, where each object is created each iteration:

```
all_items = []
for i in range(0,5):
    new_item = {}
    new_item['a'] = i
    new_item['b'] = i

    all_items.append(new_item)
    print hex(id(new_item))


 print all_items
```

You can also do in a different way, such as:

```
all_items = []
for i in range(0,5):
    new_item = {'a': i, 'b': i}
    all_items.append(new_item)
    print hex(id(new_item))    
print all_items
```

or even in one step:

```
all_items = []
for i in range(0,5):
    all_items.append({'a': i, 'b': i})

print all_items
```

Either of the following will therefore work:

```
attr = {}
attr['height'] = height 
attr['weight'] = weight

men.append(attr)
```

or:

```
men.append({'height': height, 'weight': weight})
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm not understanding it why if I use print attr. inside a loop it shows the values that I want, but when I append it to the list its append the wrongs values.

Comment: @Caaarlos I added more explanation and analogy which hopefully will help.

Comment: Yes @enderland, it really helped me, your explanation and analogy were supurb!

Comment: Such an obscure part of python. I thought I was going crazy. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 7):

You are adding the same `attr` dictionary to the list several times. The following lines will only mutate the `attr` dictionary instead of creating a new one:

```
attr['height'] = height 
attr['weight'] = weight
```

You should create a new dict each time, such as:

```
attr = {'height': height, 'weight': weight}
```

Comment: @AChampion Haha, yes, you beat me with 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the ambiguity involved in re-initializing (a step you missed) a variable in a loop and appending it to a list, Python allows you to be much more succinct.

```
height = float((random.uniform(1.3, 1.9) + (random.randint(10, 20)/100.)).__format__('.2f'))
men.append({
    'height': height,
    'weight': float((random.uniform(45, 100) * height).__format__('.2f')),
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. But, can you better explain me what am i doing wrong? Thanks for teaching me a better way to program.

Comment: I think Selcuk's answer is the explanation you're looking for. The reason this would work while your old code didn't is that there's no chance for it to simply update the values in an existing dictionary; a new one is always implicitly created via the {} syntax.

Comment: how can this work when the local variable 'height' is no longer defined?

Comment: Oops, point taken. That's what happens when you just copy and paste without reading. :) I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should Use the definition of dictionary inside the for loop instead of outside the for loop

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    attr = {}
    if gender == 0 and len(men) < 51 :
        height = float((random.uniform(1.3, 1.9) + (random.randint(10,20)/100.)).__format__('.2f'))
        weight = float((random.uniform(45, 100) * height).__format__('.2f'))
        attr['height'] = height 
        attr['weight'] = weight

        men.append(attr)
```

This gives me following output:

[{'weight': 126.75, 'height': 1.76}, {'weight': 155.35, 'height': 1.91}, {'weight': 169.2, 'height': 1.87}, {'weight': 135.54, 'height': 1.45}, {'weight': 98.58, 'height': 1.98}, {'weight': 133.73, 'height': 1.44}, {'weight': 149.48, 'height': 1.87}, {'weight': 121.93, 'height': 1.46}, {'weight': 160.09, 'height': 1.93}, {'weight': 115.62, 'height': 1.56}]

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, it has been corrected now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mutating a `dict` and appending that same `dict` over and over. You should create a new dict each time

It's also much clearer to use `round` instead of convert to str and back to float

```
if gender == 0 and len(men) < 51 :
    height = round(random.uniform(1.3, 1.9) + (random.randint(10, 20)/100.), 2)
    weight = round(random.uniform(45, 100) * height, 2)
    men.append({'height' : height, 'weight', weight})
```