# converts this list of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples.

```
list = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
```

I want to converts this list of tuples into a dictionary.

Output:

```
{'a': [1, 3, 2], 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [1]}
```

My code:

```
list_a = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
new_dict = {}
value = []
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    key = list_a[i][0]
    
    value.append(list_a[i][1])
    
    new_dict[key] = value
print(new_dict)
```

However, my output is as follows:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]}
```

Comment: Note that there is only *one single* ``value = []``.

Comment: In the future, please include a clear problem statement/question. It is unclear what is wrong until one actually runs your code. See the [ask] and [mcve] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List on python appending always the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906411/list-on-python-appending-always-the-same-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_a = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]
new_dict = {}

for item in list_a:
    # checking the item[0] which gives the first element
    # of a tuple which is there in the key element of 
    # of the new_dict
    if item[0] in new_dict:
        new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
    else:
        # add a new data for the new key 
        # which we get by item[1] from the tuple
        new_dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]
print(new_dict)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'a': [1, 3, 2], 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [1]}
```

Comment: I didn't copy you... honest!! :) haha its so close to mine.

Answer (score 0):

One option is below. Nice and readable

Read the comments in the code below

```
list = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("a", 2), ("c", 1)]

#create dictionary
dic = {}

#iterate each item in the list
for itm in list:
    #check if first item in the tuple is in the keys of the dictionary
    if itm[0] in dic.keys():
        #if so append the list
        dic[itm[0]].append(itm[1])
    else:
        #if not create new key, value pair (value is a list as enclosed with [])
        dic[itm[0]] = [itm[1]]
```

Comment: How does this substantially differ from the accepted answer? This only seems to rename variables, and use the more inefficient ``itm[0] in dic.keys()`` instead of ``itm[0] in dic`` check.

Comment: It doesn't at all. Its nearly a carbon copy. But I started writing it before the answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

There are other builin libraries that might help you solve the problem but for the mean time we can solve it using native logic.

```
list_ = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
result = {}
for i in list_:
    result[i[0]] = (result.get(i[0]) or []) + [i[1]]

print(result)  # {'a': [1, 3, 2], 'b': [2, 1], 'c': [1]}
```

Comment: ``dict.setdefault`` exists for this.