# Why do I need to use copy in recursion (climbing stairs problems)

Tags: python, recursion, shallow-copy

I was solving one of the problems from classic interview sets and I met a strange issue. The task is to by given `number of stairs n` and possible moves (steps) `range(1,k)` return all the possible combinations for steps. My solution works just if I use `copy.copy` successful steps combination before appending it to the `all-solutions-array`. Does anyone know the reason why ??

```
import copy
def climbingStaircase(n, k, successful_steps, steps_made):
    print(n, k, successful_steps, steps_made)

    # if there n is less than 0 --> return
    if n < 0:
        print('entering here')

        return
    # if n  == 0 -> we reached the top of the stairs
    if n == 0:

        successful_steps.append(copy.copy(steps_made))

        print('entering 0')
        print(n, k, successful_steps, steps_made)
        return

    for step in range(1,k+1):


        n -= step
        steps_made.append(step)


        climbingStaircase(n, k, successful_steps, steps_made) # 0, 2, [[1,1,1,1]] [1,1,1,1]
        n += steps_made.pop() #
        # steps_made.pop()

    return

def countWays(n, k):
    successful_steps = []
    climbingStaircase(n, k,successful_steps, [])
    print(successful_steps)

countWays(4,2)
```

For example for 4,2 with copy, I get the solution:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

If I do not use copy function, everything seems wrong, it seems as if by editing, adding and popping from `steps_made` I am still somehow influencing the `successful steps`

Comment: if you dont you are just changing the original list over and over... by using copy you instead change the copy, leaving the original list intact for keeping state

Comment: Because if you don't *you will use the same list object*. Consider, `a = [];  b.append(a); b.append(a); a.append(42); print(b)` Note, you don't need to `import copy`, most built-in containers have a `.copy()` method. Also note, this is tagged with [deep-copy] but you aren't creating a deep copy, but a shallow copy

Comment: Thanks! I got a bit confused, I thought that once we are appending the list, it will copy the values of the object not the whole object to the list. Because if we do it fo integers e.g. if ' b = [ ]; c = 3; b.append(c); c= 6; print(b) --> b = [3] '

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List on python appending always the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906411/list-on-python-appending-always-the-same-value)

Comment: @MaciekWoźniak **no** it works **exactly the same** for integers. It's just that `c = 6` **doesn't mutate the `int`**, assignment **never mutates**. You get the same behavior with lists: `b = []; c = []; b.append(c); c = [42]; print(b)`. `int` objects *lack mutator methods*, i.e., they are immutable. On the other hand, `.append` *does* mutate a list. But the semantics of `.append` (and assignment) are exactly the same regardless of type. The following is very useful: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Minor correction on @juanpa.arrivillaga comment: Assignment to a bare target never mutates. Assignment to a subscription (``a[b] = c``), slice (``a[b:c] = d``) or attribute (``a.b = c``) may mutate the base (``a``) and in fact usually does.