# How to append to a list the current -and not the final after iteration- state of another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, iteration

Here is a simplified version of my code(I use for-loops with a single iteration just to "simulate" normal loops that I have in the original code):

```py
import numpy as np

b=[]
for i in range(1):
    a=np.zeros([5])
    b.append(a)
    for j in range(1):
        for h in range(5):
            a[h]=h
        b.append(a)
```

The result `b` is:

```
[array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]), array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])]
```

The `b` that I want is:

```
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4.])]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for some help with formatting the code in your question.

Comment: Short version: The first time you do `b.append(a)`, it's just a _reference to `a`_, not a copy. So when you modify `a` later with `for h in range(5): a[h]=h`, you're modifying the same object which was _referenced_ at index 0. Read this answer for more info: [List on python appending always the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35906562/1431750)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

b=[]
for i in range(1):
    a=np.zeros([5])
    b.append(a)
    for j in range(1):
        for h in range(5):
            a[h]=h
    b.append(a)
    # print(b)
    del b[0]
    # b.append(c)
    a=np.zeros([5])
    b.insert(0, a)
print(b)
```

Try this the output is what you expect :)