# Appending python lists into list issue

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do something but having trouble with lists.
I tried the following :

```
list1=[]
list2=[]

for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    list1.append(name)
    list1.append(score)
    list2.append(list1)
    list1.clear()

print(list2)
```

If I input something like :

```
2
a
1
b
2
```

I get `list2` as this:
`[[], []]`

What happened? I expected it to give me :
`[[a,1], [b,2]]`

Comment: `list2.append(list1)` adds reference of `list1` not it's copy. So you add a reference to the same list which you then clear, hence "two" (actually one) empty lists

Comment: Please try to make your title specific enough that someone doesn't need to click through and read the body before they have a rough idea of what your question is about.

Comment: This is a very good question, but I agree with Charles Duffy - please update your question title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906411/list-on-python-appending-always-the-same-value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
        list2.append(list1)
        list1.clear()
```

`list1` in the second line refers to the same object as the `list1` in the first line.  You're clearing the list that you just added to `list2`.

Instead do:

```
        list2.append(list1)
        list1 = []
```

to create a new list.  `list1` still points to an empty list, but now it points to a *different* list from the one that's in `list2`.

It would be simpler to not have a variable `list1` at all.  Instead you could do:

```
  list2=[]

  for _ in range(int(input())):
     name = input()
     score = float(input())
     list2.append([name, score])

  print(list2)
```

You could also use a list comprehension instead of `append`ing in a loop:

```
names_and_scores = [
    [input(), float(input())]
    for _ in range(int(input()))
]
print(names_and_scores)
```